# Create classic asp project in Visual Studio 2010 from scratch

Tags: asp-classic

I have always developed on ASP.NET on 2.0 and higher .NET framework.
I am trying to create a website in classic ASP from scratch using VS2010 and can't figure out how to do that.

Thanks

Comment: @John: Can you support that with a reference?

Comment: @Anthony: I don't have such a reference handy. In fact, I'm thinking of deleting the comment because I can't even remember where I saw that. I may have been thinking about Windows Server 2000.

Comment: Web Matrix from Microsoft runs on Net 4.0 and supports ASP.net, PHP and Classic ASP files.

Comment: client has an existing App in classic app and needs to add some functionality to it. I was able to do it without webmatrix

Comment: "The use of ASP pages will be supported on Windows 8 for a minimum of 10 years from the Windows 8 release date.", as per this MS Support article - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2669020
So considering Windows 8 came out in 2012, Classic ASP will be around at least till 2022

Comment: Microsoft continues to maintain Active Server Pages library and documentation resources: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa286483.aspx

Answer (score 51, accepted):

1. Create a new folder
2. Open Visual Studio
3. Choose "File" -> "Open web site"
4. Go to the recently created folder
5. Then right click -> Add New item
6. Select "HTML File"
7. Rename the file as .ASP
8. Create a new web site or virtual directory in IIS and point to the folder
9. Profit!

(alternatively to 8, you can use the new IIS Express that supports ASP Classic)

Comment: just want to add a step to ur answer:- I also installed a ASP component in IIS using "windows features" in windows 7. IIS->WWW Services-> App dev features-> ASP (tick and ok)

Comment: Dont forget to enable 32 bits application on IIS using an exclusive application pool for classic asp applications. You can also enable debugging on server and debugging on client

Answer (score 9):

As you probably know, classic asp has nothing to do with .NET.  There is no type of project in VS 2010 (or any Visual Studion .NET) for classic asp sites.  If you want to use VS2010 you can simply create text file with the extension .asp and start typing away.
You can use any text editor for the job.  My favorites are primal script (greatest intellisense I have found for classic asp) and Notepad++
You don´t have to compile anything since asp is scripting language and will be interpreted each time.
So just start creating text files with asp endings and fire away.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use something for classic ASP from/supported by Microsoft then you should consider Web Matrix which includes IIS Express and is a free download.

It does require ASP.net 4.0 if not already installed.