# Managing classic ASP sites with VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp-classic

I have been given control of a web site in Classic ASP. What is the best way to manage this code with VS 2010? More specifically, how can I best import it into VS 2010. Should I start with a blank solution? A blank ASP.NET project? Obviously I'm expecting it to run through a build process, but I would still want to create it in a way so that I can edit the files with VS 2010 and run it on my debugging web server when needed for testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i'm not wrong, you can't run a classic asp website trough a build process.

In visual studio 2010 you can only open the file and edit them as a file editor. But there's not a lot of interaction between classoc asp and vs2010

Also : read this it'll help you - [Create classic asp project in Visual Studio 2010 from scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125505/create-classic-asp-project-in-visual-studio-2010-from-scratch)

Comment: You aren't wrong, you can't run a classic ASP website from VS2010.  An IIS server is required.  Eduardo's answer that you link pretty much covers it.