# Where to write ASP Code in visual studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, asp-classic

A silly question to ask. Actually I am a developer in ASP.NET, but as per the project requirements, I have to work on Classic ASP. Now I would like to know how and where to write the Classic ASP code in MS VISUAL STUDIO-2008. Since when we start a new website it says ASP.NET Website and not ASP.

Comment: This question answers your query.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125505/create-classic-asp-project-in-visual-studio-2010-from-scratch

Answer (score 0):

A little search on SO will lead you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129122/394028) It should works also in VS2008

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new item in your project, choose text file and change the extension to asp.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write code of classic-asp in visual studio then write it in source file
which is the design page. Dont write it in class(.cs) file.
But my suggestion is if you wanna write efficient code of classic-asp then
 use Dreamweaver