# start programming in asp classic

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis, asp-classic

i am trying to start a new classic asp website, i tried to understand how to do that but i couldnt figure it out.
i saw that the most common platform is webmatrix but when im trying to install it the web platform installer says i need win 7 or more and i have win xp.
i saw i can start it with visual studio (i already have) but i couldnt realy understand what i need to do with the iis, i tried to work with this:

[Create classic asp project in Visual Studio 2010 from scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125505/create-classic-asp-project-in-visual-studio-2010-from-scratch)

but i still dont realy know what to do with this "Create a new web site or virtual directory in IIS and point to the folder". i have installed iis and i have the wwwroot folder but i still dont know what to do.

what do i need to do to run the classic asp on visual studio? or if there is better platform which one it is?

thank you.

Comment: erm, why, claasic is sort of dead. should be on mvc

Comment: i know it is but i just started a project and i have told to do it on classic asp so i cant decide on my own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Classic ASP you just create a folder, stick your files in it and if they contain classic asp code then give them the .asp extension.  The w3schools tutorial is a good place to start

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_intro.asp

All you really need is a text editor. VS has good support for Classic ASP including syntax highlighting and intellisense.  The problem with VS is that the inbuilt server doesn't support Classic, only .net.  If you're running XP Pro then it comes with IIS so you can use that as your development server, if you just have the home edition then there's no easy way to set up a development environment - you might like to take a look at Active Local Pages as a last resort.

http://www.activelocalpages.com/

You can get away with Notepad, although I'd recommend something with sytntax highlighting/colouring such as EditPlus or NotePad++.  Dreamweaver actually isn't bad for editing Classic ASP sites, although don't use any of its inbuilt wizards to generate code, it'll take ten lines to do what you can do in one if you write it yourself.

Lastly, ignore the haters.  Classic ASP still has its uses :)